# Returning null fields in a solr query

Tags: javascript, solr

Let's say I have 4 fields in my solr (4.10.3) table:

```
name
date
age
state
```

If I do a simple solr query,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true
```

and one of these fields is not populated for a particular row, I'll see this:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Brian",
        "date":"2016-05-22",
        "age":"5",
        "_version_":1540387858163957773}]
  }}
```

For this query - the row did **not** have `state` populated, so `state` is not returned, but it has a `name`, `date`, and `age`, so those **are** returned.  This is very frustrating when I'm trying to take a solr return and add it into something that requires the various arrays to all have the same fields in the same order - so I wrote another script to go back in once the solr response is returned and ADD back in fields that are missing.  This of course, is expensive and it seems like a horrible way to code what I'm coding.

I have searched online though and I haven't figured out any way to get solr to return something like this:

```
{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":0,
        "params":{
          "q":"*:*",
          "indent":"true",
          "wt":"json"}},
      "response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[
          {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Brian",
            "date":"2016-05-22",
            "age":"5",
            "state":null, //or blank, or anything really?
            "_version_":1540387858163957773}]
      }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are basically asking for a default value when one is not provided, to ensure something is returned. You can define the default value per field, by providing parameter [default](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields).

```
<field name="diffType" type="string" stored="true" default=""/>
```

You will need to reindex to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Cross check in your schema.xml file about `state` field. it should have stored="true"

`<field name="state" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

if not, set stored="true"

Reload the core or restart solr. Now query its show `state` field in the response.

if you didn't get the null field, 
Reindex the documents and query again you will see the null field. like below

```
{
        "id":"DF-003",
        "name":"",
        "_version_":1544281838855389184
}
```

FYI schema.xml file will be inside conf folder.

Comment: stored=true means the field will show up if present in the document. It still will *not* show up if empty.

Comment: correct. I mentioned to reindex the document which has null field to reflect the changes. stored=true just to show field of document in the result.